# How to see values of different flags and content of registers in MASM32

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I have a requirement where I need to initialize a few registers, execute a few instructions and see the values of different flags (like CF, OF, SF, ZF, AF, and PF) and contents of the registers at the end of last instruction. I am working on windows 8 and am using qeditor that comes with masm32.

I am not restricted to use any specific editor. i.e i'm fine with any editor or compiler as long as it is a masm assembler.! Could anyone let me know what needs to be done to meet the requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is where I will say RTFM!  Click the help menu in QEeditor and read the help files.  The MASM32 Library Reference contains help for a proc called `StdOut` that will print strings, so you will have to convert the value in a register to a string.

MASM32 Macro High Level Reference, in the Macro categorie > Console Mode Macros, there is a macro called print that will print just about anything, but again you will need to convert the value to a string.  This can be done with the help of other macros.

Here is what I did:

```
include masm32rt.inc

.code
main:

    mov     ebx, 10
    print "The value of ebx is: "
    print str$(ebx), 13, 10

    mov     ebx, 2065
    print "The value of ebx is: "
    print str$(ebx), 13, 10   

    mov     eax, 34
    mov     ebx, eax
    print "The value of eax is: "
    print str$(ebx), 13, 10      

    inkey
    ret
end main
```

Noticed that I moved the value of eax into ebx to print it.  That is because if I were to use the registers `eax`, `ecx`, `edx` they would get overwritten since they are volatile registers.  So to print the volatile registers, move the value into a non-volatile register: `esi`, `edi`, `ebx`.

Comment: Thats a great help, my addition result was coming wrong, and i was using print statement in every step, still unable to debug it, i removed all print instructions and voila! the result was correct, then i inferred that maybe either eax is getting overwritten or print statement is affecting carry flag :D Hope this helps someone else too

Answer (score 0):

```
  call DumpRegs
```

will print all register values and flags

Comment: This should be comment and not an answer!!!  `DumpRegs` is not part of the MASM32 package, but instead part of Kip Irvines source code to his book, you should of mentioned that!